An error occurs when inserting functions in Excel from Python
for index, row in df.iterrows():
if row.get(access_column) == 'Доступно':
_, image_links = process_row(index, row, url_column, clip_id_column, access_column)
df.at[index, link_column_name] = '\n'.join(image_links)
total_links_count += len(image_links)
image_column_name = "Image"
image_column_values = ['@=IMAGE("' + link + '")' if link else '' for link in df[link_column_name]]

df[image_column_name] = image_column_values
output_excel_path = f'{excel_path[:-5]}_image_links.xlsx'
df.to_excel(output_excel_path, index=False, engine='openpyxl')

But in Excel, the formula is written as =@image("link")
The function works when you pick up @ if you pick up in excel. If you take it through the python code, the problem is not solved

It's supposed to be @=image("link") ? Works for me
